# Command prompt truncates command call

Tags: windows-7, command-line, r, rstudio

I am trying to build a package through Rstudio, but something is going wrong with the `system()` calls it sends to command prompt:

```
"//networkpath/JDUB~PN6/DOCU~UZL/R/R-34~TN4.0/bin/x64/R"  \
  --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "R:\NL\Database Marketing\R library\independeR" --build -d --preclean 

'\\networkpath\JDUB~PN6\DOCU~UZL\R\R-34~TN4.0' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

For some reason command prompt truncates the command `"//networkpath/JDUB~PN6/DOCU~UZL/R/R-34~TN4.0/bin/x64/R"` to `'\\networkpath\JDUB~PN6\DOCU~UZL\R\R-34~TN4.0'`.

If I manually enter the call to `system()` in command prompt, the same thing happens.

Why does this happen and is there a way to fix it?

Edit: In the meanwhile I found a workaround in R, but for the sake of this question, I would still like to find out why command prompt is doing this.

Comment: How many characters is that path in total ?

Comment: The entire path, including `/R` is 67 characters, excluding the quotes.

Comment: The truncated command is 57 characters, including `R-34~TN4.0`.

Comment: Might be asking a stupid question here, but what's with send forward slashes to the Command Prompt?

Comment: @Twisty The command I am trying to run is created by `R`'s `devtools::build()`. The path to `R` is created by the function `R.home()` which returns forward slashes.

Comment: Try this:  //networkpath/JDUB~PN6/DOCU~UZL/R/"R-34~TN4.0/bin"/x64/R  \
  --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "R:\NL\Database Marketing\R library\independeR" --build -d --preclean

Comment: @Overmind Same problem.

Comment: In the meanwhile I found a workaround in R, but for the sake of this question, I would still like to find out why command prompt is doing this.

Comment: Did it fail at the exact same character ?

Comment: Yes, with the exact same output.

Comment: If I `cd` to `//networkpath/JDUB~PN6/DOCU~UZL/R/` first, and then provide the rest of the path to the command, it does work.

Comment: In that case, store the two parts in 2 variables and use them instead.

Comment: So the path with command combined is simply too long for command prompt to handle?

Comment: If there's a limit to how long a command can be, I'm not aware of it, but you're certainly no where near it with this command.